# How do I configure OpenSSH to not use the "-sk" versions of keys for hardware authenticators?

Tags: openssh

I have a system that needs to connect to several clients through SSH keys. This is in a somewhat legacy environment, and clients have varying OS and SSH versions.

I created a new ed25519 host key on the server:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

Then I distributed that key to some clients using `ssh-copy-id`. On attempting to connect, the key exchange is unsuccessful because the OpenSSH client tries to send the ["-sk" variant of the key](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/240991/what-is-the-sk-ending-for-ssh-key-types), which is normally reserved for use with hardware tokens and hence not used on my machine.

Here's an excerpt from the ssh debug output during a connection attempt:

```
$ ssh -vvv user@targethost
...
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/backuppc/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /var/lib/backuppc/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/backuppc/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /var/lib/backuppc/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Offering public key: /var/lib/backuppc/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:/uHOQ+Z2mYCkmHJ14xwskJ6Fhl+Ez2LNswd2pReD4ZA
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/backuppc/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /var/lib/backuppc/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
```

You can see that the ECDSA exchange attempts to send both the "normal" and the "_sk" variants of the key. However, for my ED25519 key, the connection seems to only try the "_sk" variant of the private key.

How and where can this behaviour be configured?